# Meaning of variable in array as property name?

Tags: javascript

```
var expertise = 'journalism'
var person = {
    name: 'Sharon',
    age: 27,
    [expertise]: {
        years: 5,
        interests: ['international', 'politics', 'internet']
    }
}
```

In this expression, why are we considering `[expertise]` in brackets as property name? What's the need to put bracket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So that, you can refer to the string value stored in the `expertise` variable, that is, `journalism`.

```js
var expertise = 'journalism'
var person = {
name: 'Sharon',
age: 27,
[expertise]: {
years: 5,
interests: ['international', 'politics', 'internet']
}
}

console.log(person.journalism.years);
console.log(person[expertise].years);
```

Run this code snippet, and note the two console logs.

Without the brackets, you'd have the string `"expertise"` instead, as the property name.

You can read more about it here on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

> **Computed property names**
>
> Starting with ECMAScript 2015, the object
>   initializer syntax also supports computed property names. That allows
>   you to put an expression in brackets [], that will be computed as the
>   property name. This is symmetrical to the bracket notation of the
>   property accessor syntax, which you might have used to read and set
>   properties already. Now you can use the same syntax in object
>   literals, too

```
var param = 'size';
var config = {
  [param]: 12,
  ['mobile' + param.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + param.slice(1)]: 4
};

console.log(config); // {size: 12, mobileSize: 4}
```

Answer (score 7):

It is syntactic sugar, introduced in `ECMAScript 6`

[Computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

> Starting with ECMAScript 2015, the object initializer syntax also supports computed property names. That allows you to put an expression in brackets [], that will be computed as the property name. This is symmetrical to the bracket notation of the property accessor syntax, which you might have used to read and set properties already.

#### ECMAScript 5

```
var expertise = 'journalism'
var person = {
    name: 'Sharon',
    age: 27
}
person[expertise] = {
    years: 5,
    interests: ['international', 'politics', 'internet']
}
```

#### ECMAScript 6

```
var expertise = 'journalism'
var person = {
    name: 'Sharon',
    age: 27,
    [expertise]: {
        years: 5,
        interests: ['international', 'politics', 'internet']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is [`Computed property (ES2015)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) :

This is a sample:

```
var prop = 'foo';
var o = {
  [prop]: 'hey',
  ['b' + 'ar']: 'there'
};
```

and you may use :

```
console.log(o.foo)  // hey
console.log(o.bar)  // there
```